# Topological entanglement entropy only defined for a system in the ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, topological-order, topological-field-theory, topological-entropy

What happens to the topological entanglement entropy of a system, when it is driven out of its groundstate by increasing the temperature?

Comment: This question may be answered in general, but it always helps if one starts with simple concrete models. A good starting point is [this paper](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v76/i18/e184442).

Comment: Here is a free version of the paper linked above (http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3616)